# Why this code piece is producing this error?

Tags: python

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import print_function
    import io
    import os
    from os.path import dirname, join

    from alembic import command
    from alembic.config import Config
    import baker

    from webapp.database import db
    from webapp.main import app
    import webapp.areas.manage
    import webapp.users.manage
    import webapp.planner.manage
    import webapp.tests.manage


    @baker.command
    def load_data():
```

```
    traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 11, in 
        from webapp.database import db
      File "/var/www/project01/webapp/database/__init__.py", line 3, in 
        from .main import db
      File "/var/www/project01/webapp/database/main.py", line 6, in 
        from ..app import app
      File "/var/www/project01/webapp/app.py", line 37, in 
        default_timezone="America/Lima"
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/allspeak.py", line 30, in __init__
        super(Allspeak, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/i18n.py", line 33, in __init__
        self.load_translations()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/i18n.py", line 50, in load_translations
        self.translations = self.reader.load_translations(locales=locales)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/reader.py", line 129, in load_translations
        self._update_translations(translations, filepath)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/reader.py", line 96, in _update_translations
        data = self._load_file(filepath)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/reader.py", line 90, in _load_file
        return self._extract_locales(data)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/reader.py", line 81, in _extract_locales
        for locale, trans in data.items()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: `from webapp.database import db`
`from webapp.main import app`
`import webapp.areas.manage`
`import webapp.users.manage`
`import webapp.planner.manage`
`import webapp.tests.manage`

Comment: That is the code in my manage.py file...I think the issue is in the import section.

Comment: Please [edit] it into your question.

Comment: from the error log it looks like the error is in the file reader.py not with the code u have put at the start of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code, I am having to guess this a fair bit. Attribute error means u are trying to access a attribute of an object that doesn't exist.

For example if I have an object called rectangle. It has two attributes width and length; now if I try to use this rectangle and try to access an attribute called radius it would produce an error as that attribute for that object does not exist.

Comment: but note that issue is in this line : `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/allspeak/reader.py`

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand why the issue is in the python library, I am php developer and I cannot understand this.

Comment: i haven't used php before sorry

Comment: `Hello Friends I think I am near to find the issue`...`the bug is produced for a relative import` `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: here the code : from .. import config inside the 'database' package, it seems we need some variables from the 'config' package

Answer (score 2):

```
File "/var/www/comunidadsm/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allspeak/reader.py", line 79, in _extract_locales
for locale, trans in data.items()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'

Perhaps changing that line to:
for locale,trans in (data.items() if data else [])

Not sure if that syntax will work right here, but it is an attempt
```

to pass a null list if data is not None, skipping over the loop.
Probably not the best solution, but you can find out what goes
on after it.